# Is it possible to integrate Google Analytics in my JS library

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a JS library which is used by some users. I am going to track some behaviours from user using the library. I tried to configure a property on Google Analytics, however, it seems I should configure a URL for a website, an ID for an ios or an Android application.

[image]

How can I use Google Analytics in my library? Or can GA be used for this purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Analytics is a web analytics tool. So you won't be able to track your JS library with GA.

If you Google “Google Analytics,” the description provided is as following:

Google Analytics lets you measure your advertising ROI and track your Flash, video, and social networking sites and applications.

JS libraries are not part of the use cases.

Also, Google “Track JS Library Google Analytics.” As you can see, you’ll only get references to libraries such as gtag.js or analytics.js, which will not serve your purpose of tracking your library.

And ask yourself, will people use your JS library when they know you are tracking them? I don't think so. Instead, create a repo on GitHub with documentation and allow users to report issues.

Also, create a mailing list with users and execute small surveys to understand better how people are using your JS library.

Comment: Thanks @Raoul for your answer. Do you have any reference? If as you said, GA doesn't work for a library, do you know any replacement?